# Audio tag error Object doesn't support proeprty or method 'load'

Tags: html, html5-audio

I have included a test audio player on a site and it works fine with all the browser but doesn't work on IE. It throws an error "Object doesn't support proeprty or method 'load'" on Console every time I try to select an audio file to play

Following the code

```
<label for="selection">Try Sound file here:</label>
<select id="selection" onchange="selectFile(this)">
<option value="">- Select sound -</option>
<%
for (String sound : soundFileNames) {
%>
<option value="<%=sound%>" ><%=sound%></option>
<%} %>
</select>
<br/>

<audio id="player" controls="controls">
<source id="mp3_src" src="<%=rSoundFilePath%>ding.mp3" type="audio/mp3" 
/>Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<script>
function selectFile(selection) {
  var soundFile  = selection.value; 
  var audio = document.getElementById("player");
  var source = document.getElementById("mp3_src");  
  var location = getContextPath()+"/test/Audio/theme/sound/" + soundFile;
  if (soundFile) {
    source.src = location;
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  }
}

function getContextPath() {
   return window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2));
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had you check the compatibility of your code with IE. Whether IE version you are using supports that?  It's more on HTML 5 which may your IE not supports.

Comment: It sometimes works when I do Ctrl+F5 multiple times.
Also I am using this element in other js too, where I am playing the sound and it works fine there too.

Comment: that is strange but true...why should I waste praying for this pity thing in life :-;

Comment: That's a comment not an answer.